# Get the size of a directory (not its content)

Tags: c++, filesystems, std, filesize

(please before dismissing this as already answered, read the full question)

In C++ we can get the file size of a regular file by running `std::filesystem::file_size(PATH);` But this function does not work on directories, which is my problem.
I am in a situation where I need to know the size of directory "inode", in (most) linux systems the standard size of a directory is 4kB or block size:

```sh
$:~/tmp/test$ mkdir ex
$:~/tmp/test$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 secret secret 4096 Oct 15 08:43 ex
```

These 4kB inlcudes space for having a "list" of the file in that directory.
But if the number of files in the directory becomes significantly large, the size of the folder can increase (which is where I am).
I need to be able to track this increase.
So my question is that besides calling `ls -l` or `du` from C++ is there a C++-native way of getting the size of the directory?
I am aware that the reason it does not work with `std::filesystem::file_size(path)` is due file systems different ways of representing directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size

> For a regular file p, returns the size determined as if by reading the
> st_size member of the structure obtained by POSIX stat (symlinks are
> followed)
>
> The result of attempting to determine the size of a directory (as well
> as any other file that is not a regular file or a symlink) is
> implementation-defined.

`file_size` on a directory may actually work in some implementations, but I guess that yours doesn't. There doesn't appear to be a pure C++ alterantive, but you can call the POSIX `stat` function yourself. That does work on directories and reports the number you want.

Comment: yup implementation specific.

Comment: I had not thought about the option to use `stat` thank you so much. Seems to work